# Extremely ugly query issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If anyone can help me on this I would be very excited...I've already spent about 4 hours and cannot find out why T-SQL gives me wrong results and the same query in sql is fine(I mean only @ZipCodeIDS is not null, that's why I put null for the rest of vars in plain sql).

T-SQL Query:

```
-- validate the reference number pattern
DECLARE @PCodePattern nvarchar(130)
IF @PCode = '' SET @PCode = NULL
IF @PCode IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@PCode)) <> ''
    BEGIN
        -- filter by pattern
        SELECT @PCodePattern = @PCode 
    END
END -- @PCode

if (@strAddress is not null)
    set @strAddress = '%' + @strAddress + '%'   

Declare @listofIDS table(zipcodeids int)
delete from @listofIDS
IF @ZipCodeIDS = '' SET @ZipCodeIDS = NULL
IF @ZipCodeIDS IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(',', @ZipCodeIDS) = 0
    BEGIN
        insert @listofIDS values(@ZipCodeIDS)
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @ZipCodeIDS = @ZipCodeIDS + ','     
            WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @ZipCodeIDS) <> 0
            BEGIN
                    insert @listofIDS values(Left(@ZipCodeIDS, CHARINDEX(',',@ZipCodeIDS) - 1))
                    SET @ZipCodeIDS = SUBSTRING(@ZipCodeIDS, CHARINDEX(',',@ZipCodeIDS) + 1, LEN(@ZipCodeIDS) - CHARINDEX(',',@ZipCodeIDS))
            END
        END
END



-- select the property data
INSERT INTO @PropertyDetails (PropertyID, PCode, PropertyStatusID, PropertyStatusName,
                              PropertyTypeID, PropertyTypeName, ResearchStatusID,
                              ResearchStatusName, FullAddress, PartialAddress, Address1,
                              Address2, ZipCodeID, ZipCode, ZipCodeDescription, CityID, 
                              CityName, StateID, StateName, StateCode, NumBedrooms, NumBathrooms, 
                              LivingSquareFeet, LotSquareFeet, YearBuilt, ZillowLink, 
                              AssessorParcelNumber, DateWentREO, DateAppearedOnMLS, IsOnTheMLS, 
                              ZPropertyID, LowestPrice, HighestPrice, AskingPrice, DateTimeRecorded, 
                              RecordedByPersonID, RecordedByPersonName, AssignedToPersonID, 
                              AssignedToPersonName, WatchTag, Latitude, Longitude)
    SELECT p.PropertyID, p.PCode, p.PropertyStatusID, ps.Name, p.PropertyTypeID, pt.Name,
           p.ResearchStatusID, rs.Name, dbo.GetAddress(p.PropertyID), 
           dbo.GetPartialAddress(p.PropertyID), p.Address1, p.Address2, p.ZipCodeID, z.Code, 
           z.Description, p.CityID, c.Name, p.StateID, s.Name, s.Code, p.NumBedrooms, 
           p.NumBathrooms, p.LivingSquareFeet, p.LotSquareFeet, p.YearBuilt, p.ZillowLink, 
           p.AssessorParcelNumber, p.DateWentREO, p.DateAppearedOnMLS, p.IsOnTheMLS, 
           p.ZPropertyID, p.LowestPrice, p.HighestPrice, p.AskingPrice, p.DateTimeRecorded, 
           p.RecordedByPersonID, dbo.GetDisplayName(p.RecordedByPersonID), p.AssignedToPersonID,
           dbo.GetDisplayName(p.AssignedToPersonID), w.WatchTag, p.latitude, p.longitude
        FROM Properties p
        JOIN cfgPropertyStatuses ps
          ON ps.PropertyStatusID = p.PropertyStatusID
        JOIN cfgPropertyTypes pt
          ON pt.PropertyTypeID = p.PropertyTypeID
        JOIN cfgResearchStatuses rs
          ON rs.ResearchStatusID = p.ResearchStatusID
        JOIN ZipCodes z
          ON z.ZipCodeID = p.ZipCodeID
        JOIN cfgStates s
          ON s.StateID = p.StateID
        LEFT JOIN cfgCities c
          ON c.CityID = p.CityID
        LEFT JOIN Watches w
          ON w.PropertyID = p.PropertyID AND w.PersonID = @LoggedInPersonID
        WHERE /*
                ******* missing filter *******
                this line should filter the risks by @LoggedInPersonID via role 
                ******************************
          AND */(@PropertyID IS NULL OR p.PropertyID = @PropertyID)
          AND (@PCodePattern IS NULL OR p.PCode LIKE @PCodePattern)
          AND (@ZipCodeIDS IS NULL 
                OR p.ZipCodeID IN (select zipcodeids from @listofIDS))
          AND (@NumBedroomsFrom IS NULL OR (p.NumBedrooms >= @NumBedroomsFrom
                                                AND @NumBedroomsTo IS NOT NULL 
                                                AND p.NumBedrooms <= @NumBedroomsTo)
                                        OR (p.NumBedrooms = @NumBedroomsFrom
                                                AND @NumBedroomsTo IS NULL))
          AND (@NumBedroomsTo IS NULL OR (p.NumBedrooms <= @NumBedroomsTo
                                            AND (@NumBedroomsTo IS NULL OR p.NumBedrooms <= @NumBedroomsTo)))
          AND (@LivingSizeFrom IS NULL OR (p.LivingSquareFeet >= @LivingSizeFrom))
          AND (@LivingSizeTo IS NULL OR (p.LivingSquareFeet <= @LivingSizeTo))
          AND (@LotSizeFrom IS NULL OR (p.LotSquareFeet >= @LotSizeFrom))
          AND (@LotSizeTo IS NULL OR (p.LotSquareFeet <= @LotSizeTo))
          AND 
            /* if status is null, return all. Or, return only statuses that are passed in */
            (@PropertyStatuses IS NULL or 
                ((p.PropertyStatusID=@PropertyStatuses and (p.PropertyStatusID & (32 | 128)) = 0) or 
                @PropertyID is not null or @PCode is not null) or 
                (p.PropertyStatusID = (p.PropertyStatusID & @PropertyStatuses)))
                /*
                    -- return the property if the specific ID was given otherwise ommit Sold and Archived
                    AND ((p.PropertyStatusID & (32 /*sold*/ | 128 /*archived*/)) = 0 
                            OR @PropertyID IS NOT NULL
                            OR @PCode IS NOT NULL))
                OR (p.PropertyStatusID = (p.PropertyStatusID & @PropertyStatuses)))
                            */
          AND (@PropertyTypes IS NULL 
                OR (p.PropertyTypeID = (p.PropertyTypeID & @PropertyTypes)))
          AND (@ResearchStatuses IS NULL
                OR (p.ResearchStatusID = (p.ResearchStatusID & @ResearchStatuses)))
          AND (@IsOnTheMLS IS NULL OR p.IsOnTheMLS = @IsOnTheMLS)
          and (@strAddress is null or (p.Address1 LIKE @strAddress or p.Address2 LIKE @strAddress))
        
RETURN
```

and the same, translated by me in SQL (which works good):

```
    /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [PropertyID]
      ,[PCode]
      ,[Address1]
      ,[Address2]
      ,[NumBedrooms]
      ,[NumBathrooms]
      ,[LivingSquareFeet]
      ,[LotSquareFeet]
      ,[YearBuilt]
      ,[ZillowLink]
      ,[AssessorParcelNumber]
      ,[DateWentREO]
      ,[DateAppearedOnMLS]
      ,[IsOnTheMLS]
      ,[ZPropertyID]
      ,[LowestPrice]
      ,[HighestPrice]
      ,[AskingPrice]
      ,[DateTimeRecorded]
      ,[RecordedByPersonID]
      ,[AssignedToPersonID]
      ,[latitude]
      ,[longitude]
      ,[Zestimate]
  FROM [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].[Properties] p
            JOIN [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].cfgPropertyStatuses ps
              ON ps.PropertyStatusID = p.PropertyStatusID
            JOIN [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].cfgPropertyTypes pt
              ON pt.PropertyTypeID = p.PropertyTypeID
            JOIN [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].cfgResearchStatuses rs
              ON rs.ResearchStatusID = p.ResearchStatusID
            JOIN [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].ZipCodes z
              ON z.ZipCodeID = p.ZipCodeID
            JOIN [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].cfgStates s
              ON s.StateID = p.StateID
            LEFT JOIN [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].cfgCities c
              ON c.CityID = p.CityID
  where 
  (NULL IS NULL OR p.PropertyID = NULL)
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR p.PCode LIKE NULL)
              AND ('1' IS NULL 
                    OR p.ZipCodeID IN (select zipcodeids from [dev_hotsheetDB].[dbo].[listofIDS]))
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR (p.NumBedrooms >= NULL
                                                    AND NULL IS NOT NULL 
                                                    AND p.NumBedrooms <= NULL)
                                            OR (p.NumBedrooms = NULL
                                                    AND NULL IS NULL))
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR (p.NumBedrooms <= NULL
                                                AND (NULL IS NULL OR p.NumBedrooms <= NULL)))
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR (p.LivingSquareFeet >= NULL))
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR (p.LivingSquareFeet <= NULL))
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR (p.LotSquareFeet >= NULL))
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR (p.LotSquareFeet <= NULL))
              AND 
                /* if status is null, return all. Or, return only statuses that are passed in */
                (NULL IS NULL or 
                    ((p.PropertyStatusID=NULL and (p.PropertyStatusID & (32 | 128)) = 0) or 
                    NULL is not null or NULL is not null) or 
                    (p.PropertyStatusID = (p.PropertyStatusID & NULL)))
                    /*
                        -- return the property if the specific ID was given otherwise ommit Sold and Archived
                        AND ((p.PropertyStatusID & (32 /*sold*/ | 128 /*archived*/)) = 0 
                                OR @PropertyID IS NOT NULL
                                OR @PCode IS NOT NULL))
                    OR (p.PropertyStatusID = (p.PropertyStatusID & @PropertyStatuses)))
                                */
              AND (NULL IS NULL 
                    OR (p.PropertyTypeID = (p.PropertyTypeID & NULL)))
              AND (NULL IS NULL
                    OR (p.ResearchStatusID = (p.ResearchStatusID & NULL)))
              AND (NULL IS NULL OR p.IsOnTheMLS = NULL)
              and (NULL is null or (p.Address1 LIKE NULL or p.Address2 LIKE NULL))
```

Please note that the issue is only related to `IN` statement... When @ZipCodeIDS = '1,2,3' it should return  414 results (plain sql ok) but T-SQL function returns 80..

**The strange thing I've noticed is that T-SQL only takes in consideration FIRST id from @ZipCodeIDS** (as you see I split these ids and put them into a temp table). So here's the issue - about this first id... (cannot confirm that this is the only issue, because there were times when for the first zipCodeId it shouldn't return anything but it still returned results)

Can you give a helping hand please?
Ps: for my plain sql query, I've used a real table with those ids, just to mimic the behavior as much as possible...

**UPDATE**: The splitting of the @ZipCodeIDS and insertion into the temp table works perfectly: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/109406/

Comment: declare a table var and then delete from it: why?

Comment: Sorry, that was a test to make sure the table is empty... trust me, that this is very ugly so I've tried to make sure for some other things also even if these are OK in 'real life'

Comment: No argument about the ugly...But your statement is false; you don't need to code for impossibles.

Comment: Is your input parameter for @ZipCodeIDS correct? It sounds a little like you've got a varchar(1) - hence it's only using the first id. Have you tried changing the IN condition in the function to the same as in your test SQL? It would be sensible to isolate it to this part of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue with Timbo help!!!!!

I've declared `@ZipCodeIDS varchar` and somehow it is made by default VARCHAR(1).

I changed it to @ZipCodeIDS varchar(50) and not it perfectly works!!!!

Sorry guys because this declaration was hidden from you!